# Codeigniter concat_ws not working

Tags: codeigniter

**Getting error when I tried like this:**

```
    $ci =& get_instance();              
    $ci->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ',users.name_first,users.name_last) AS user_name,CONCAT_WS(' ',advertisers.name_first,advertisers.name_last) AS advertiser_name,image,advertiser_reviews.last_updated");

            $ci->db->join('users', 'users.id = advertiser_reviews.user_id');
            $ci->db->join('advertisers', 'advertisers.id = advertiser_reviews.advertiser_id');
            $ci->db->order_by('advertiser_reviews.id','desc');
            $ci->db->limit(1);
            $query = $ci->db->get('advertiser_reviews');
```

**Error as follows:**

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`hc_advertiser_reviews`) JOIN `hc_users` ON `hc_users`.`id` = `hc_advertis' at line 2

SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `hc_users`.`name_first`, `hc_users`.`name_last)` AS user_name, 
       CONCAT_WS(' ', `hc_advertisers`.`name_first`, `hc_advertisers`.`name_last)` AS advertiser_name, 
       `image`, 
       `hc_advertiser_reviews`.`last_updated` 
FROM (`hc_advertiser_reviews`) 
    JOIN `hc_users` ON `hc_users`.`id` = `hc_advertiser_reviews`.`user_id` 
    JOIN `hc_advertisers` ON `hc_advertisers`.`id` = `hc_advertiser_reviews`.`advertiser_id` 
ORDER BY `hc_advertiser_reviews`.`id` desc LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use `$this->db->query("your sql query")`

EDIT:
try to avoid the auto-quoting feature of the CodeIgniter DB class with

```
$this->db->select("your-query",FALSE)
```

Comment: $this->db->query("your sql query") is only like 'mysql_query' and it is not framework like coding. I want to know, what is the error in my coding?

Comment: try to avoid the auto-quoting feature of the CI DB class, $this->db->select("<query>",FALSE)

Comment: Thanks Christian. That is working fine without backticks in select query.

Comment: FWIW, the only benefit of using "framework like coding" for a simple MySQL-specific query like this one is decreased code readability. It's been (quite successfully) argued that you can save yourself a lot of headache by running straight queries when you don't need additional logic to help you build the query.

Answer (score 0):

There is sign ` at the Codeigniter generated code at the end

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `hc_users`.`name_first`, `hc_users`.`name_last)`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('what of sql uncion' ,false);
```

the false tell ci to ignor escaping with `

Comment: myavbe after the last endit of that post edited Feb 21 at 17:44 :) 20 minuts later

Comment: Wrong, that last edit was mine and it's only format. The [second revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9773445/2) is from Feb 19.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this post where I had the same issue and you can get around the issue by a clever use of spaces.

```
$ci->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ',users.name_first,users.name_last ) AS user_name )
```

As opposed to

```
$ci->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ',users.name_first,users.name_last) AS user_name )
```

If you insert a space before the last closing bracket of the CONCAT_WS function then the CodeIgniter auto-quoting feature won't get confused about where the `s need to go. It also means you dont have to use the db->query() function.